# Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected

Tags: android

I am developing android application for android tablets and I try do that when device is charging connect turn on to device.Is it possible to automatically power on the android device when charging is connected?

Comment: i didn't saw devices that don't turn on screen with charge. Any way you have to use `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which device is it. You basically need to update the battery loading animation file with a shell script to restart the device, but you have to know which file is responsible for animating your battery icon. Each OEM has its own standard of naming/locating the animation file and you should find yours.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to register broadcast receiver for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED ':

```
BroadcastReceiver PowerStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent batteryStatus = context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null,
                                new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
assert batteryStatus != null;
status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
```

and you will have 2 options:

```
if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL) {
// device plugged
// ...
}else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING) {
// device unplugged
// ...
}
```

and:

```
IntentFilter powerConnectedFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(PowerStatusReceiver, powerConnectedFilter);
```

And to keep the screen on while the device is plugged, see: [Android Keep Screen On In App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342767/android-keep-screen-on-in-app)

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I want to do that when the device plugged if device turn off,device will be turn on.your answer for the a applicaiton

Comment: Ok. Now I got it... I think you can do this only hardware, because if the device is turned off, then the Android OS is not running, and for sure, any app can not handle this. :) Could be 2 solutions: rewrite the bootloader of the device (with a custom one), or a electronic circuit tied between the USB plug and the power button. None of the options is not universal :(